# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLFormElement> has no method onkeydown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to figure out how to get a comment to post from my textarea input box and in my console in chrome i keep getting this error.

Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'add_comment' initiative_tracker:1
onkeydown

tried this jquery bit first to no avail.

```
$('.cmnt_new').on('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13 && ! e.shiftKey) {
        // your AJAX call
    }
});
```

I've tried just about everything, starting with some nice clean jquery and now i'm just working on some inline JS.

Inline JS that i'm now trying to get working

Please any help would be greatly appreciated, i'm struggling on this.

Comment: Inline JS is never the answer.

Comment: `this.form.add_comment()` is your problem; what do you expect that to do?

Comment: @Mathletics It's pretty self explanatory? Isn't it? Add comment to this form? It's just horribly wrong.

Comment: I've been told to stay away from inline JS from other people as well. I'm trying to use that function to create a new comment row and display it, at this point it's suppose to add a comment to the DB and the UI.

Comment: @cook There's no point in inline js as you're using jquery, selecting elements to do stuff with is relatively easy ;)

Comment: I can get my jQuery to work in fiddle but not on my site.  http://jsfiddle.net/Tentonaxe/5JKy8/

Comment: I'm pretty sure i need to send the TD.cmnt_save for that row.  Then the existing function will sniff-out all of the other references it needs to take action on the page. I'm just in need of help figuring out how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap `this.form` with a jquery selector, and reverse the order of the call (`add_comment` is NOT a method of the form, but a function of the window): `add_comment($(this.form))`

Alternatively, you can use jQuery extensions to define add_comments as a jQuery plugin. More on that [here](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/).

Comment: Like this?  this.form.add_comment($(this.form)); return false; or just  add_comment($(this.form)); return false;

Comment: it looks like it wants to work but i'm getting an undefined for my "id" parameter. Notice the differences in the url after i hit enter and try to submit. the first url is through the regular method and the second is through your addition. `comment_new.php?id=4&text=hello&emp_init=ADZ`
`comment_new.php?id=undefined&text=hello&emp_init=ADZ`  the id is undefined... any more help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure i need to send the TD.cmnt_save for that row.  Then the existing function will sniff-out all of the other references it needs to take action on the page. I'm just in need of help figuring out how to do that.